# How to undo wordpress redirect URL setting?

Tags: php, wordpress

I went to 'Settings' in the WordPress admin menu and then clicked on 'Website Redirect', then I entered a URL to redirect the site to, but now I no longer have access to site/wp-admin login page, but rather another new_url/wp-login.php page with some login credentials I do not know.

How to undo this URL change and set it back to the previous settings?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue (why would credentials have changed?), but you'll need access to the database to revert options if you can't access admin.

Comment: Thank you @CK_MacLeod, what should be modified in the DB to revert the options?

Comment: @TiyebM did you change the WordPress Address in settings? If so this is found in the wp_options table of the databse.

Comment: If you you've changed the setting under General/Site Address (URL), then it will usually be one of the very first options in the wp_options table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think it's almost always the very first option in the options table. Just in case there's any confusion based on the below example and the other comment above, the tables are sometimes prefixed `wp_` by default - as in a "classic" installation - but you'll very often find them with a custom prefix.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

you guys ROCK! I had to go to a different table. Below is a screenshot...the table name is nNarToptions. The redirect was right there ...easy edit.  [image]